# Calculate Eucleudian distance between 20pairs of Amio acids using thieir Physicochemical properties scores in Python and the output is a Matrix

Tags: python, matrix, distance

Can someone help me?

I have 20 amino-acids (AAs) and 7 physochemichal properties (RADA880102; FAUJ880103; ZIMJ680104; GRAR740102;CRAJ730103; BURA740101; CHAM820102)

The input is a tab delimited text file and it looks like this:

```
 Amino-acids    A   R   N   D   C   Q   E   G   H   I   L   K   M   F   P   S   T   W   Y   V
RADA880102  0.52    -1.32   -0.01   0   0   -0.07   -0.79   0   0.95    2.04    1.76    0.08    1.32    2.09    0   0.04    0.27    2.51    1.63    1.18
FAUJ880103  1   6.13    2.95    2.78    2.43    3.95    3.78    0   4.66    4   4   4.77    4.43    5.89    2.72    1.6 2.6 8.08    6.47    3
ZIMJ680104  6   10.76   5.41    2.77    5.05    5.65    3.22    5.97    7.59    6.02    5.98    9.74    5.74    5.48    6.3 5.68    5.66    5.89    5.66    5.96
GRAR740102  8.1 10.5    11.6    13  5.5 10.5    12.3    9   10.4    5.2 4.9 11.3    5.7 5.2 8   9.2 8.6 5.4 6.2 5.9
CRAJ730103  0.6 0.79    1.42    1.24    1.29    0.92    0.64    1.38    0.95    0.67    0.7 1.1 0.67    1.05    1.47    1.26    1.05    1.23    1.35    0.48
BURA740101  0.486   0.262   0.193   0.288   0.2 0.418   0.538   0.12    0.4 0.37    0.42    0.402   0.417   0.318   0.208   0.2 0.272   0.462   0.161   0.379
CHAM820102  -0.368  -1.03   0   2.06    4.53    0.731   1.77    -0.525  0   0.791   1.07    0   0.656   1.06    -2.24   -0.524  0   1.6 4.91    0.401
```

I am trying to write a script in Python to compute the  Euclidean distance for each pair of AAs using the following formula

```
dist = sqrt[Σ[(xa-xb)^2 + (ya-yb)^2 + (za-zb)^2 + (ma-mb)^2 + (na-nb)^2 + (pa-pb)^2 + (ra-rb)^2]]
```

Where (xa, ya, za,  ma,  na, pa and ra) indicate one of the seven physicochemical properties of original AA and (xb, yb, zb, mb, nb, pb and rb) indicate the other one of the seven physicochemical properties of the substituting AA respectively.

For instance the Euclidian distance between two AAs A and R will looks like this
dist = sqrt[Σ[(0.52-(-1.32))^2 + (1-6.13)^2 + (6-10.76)^2 + (8.1-10.5)^2 + (0.6-0.79)^2 + (0.486-0.262)^2 + (-0.368-(-1.03))^2]]

The original formula can be found at this link on page 2 
"http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3589708/pdf/fgene-04-00021.pdf"

I would like my script to return a Matrix of Euclidian distance as the output with 380 values

```
A   R   N   D   C   Q   E   G   H   I   L   K   M   F   P   S   T   W   Y   V
```

A
R
N
D
C
Q
E
G
H
I
L
K
M
F
P
S
T
W
Y
V

Thank you for any help

Comment: so which part are you stuck at?

Comment: Joran BeasleyI don't know how to write a script with a formula that will return a Matrix

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment the part you are stuck on is creating a matrix to return from a function

```
def zeros_matrix(width,height):
    return [[0 for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
```

will return a matrix of all zeros  further since I doubt that is the only place you are stuck

to open a file and read it into a matrix

```
with open("some_file") as f:
     matrix = map(str.split,f)

print matrix
```

to calculate the dist between 2 rows

```
import math
def row_dist(row1,row2):
   dist = #some calculation I dont really understand
   return dist

print sorted(matrix,key=row_dist)
```

Comment: Joran Beasley Thank you for your help. I have been experiencing issues at the beginning. How do I import the text file into Python  To be honest with you, the formula is from page 2 on the following  link "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3589708/pdf/fgene-04-00021.pdf". Because I was unable to copy and past it here, I tried to rewrite it on my own

Comment: You are right the row represent the 20 amino acids and the columns are the 7 physicochemical properties

Comment: Joran Beasley. I have been experiencing issues at the beginning. How do I import the text file into Python To be honest with you, the formula is from page 2 on the following link "ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3589708/pdf/…;. Because I was unable to copy and past it here, I tried to rewrite it on my own